# Stack object with max limit

Tags: c#

The C# Stack object is nice to handle an infinite stack. But is there a way to limit it (or a similar object) that can limit to a certain number of stacked elements? I also wants the oldest one (first inserted) to be removed if max+1 elements are added.

Comment: "I also wants the oldest one (first inserted) to be removed if max+1 elements are added." - then you can't use a stack...

Comment: Stacks are first in / last out, you want a queue, which is first in first out

Comment: You can use Stack(int size) constructor to define its capicity

Comment: @voo: That's just the initial capacity, not a hard limit.

Comment: @Shane.C : LIFO is what I want, but truncate the oldest (first) one.

Comment: Fair enough, take a look at the answers suggesting Curcular Buffer then : )

Answer (score 5):

The .NET Framework does not provide a data structure with the properties you describe. However, you should be able to create your own data structure easily by taking a [Circular Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) and changing it from FIFO to LIFO.

Comment: +1. There are many implementations, [this search query](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+circular+buffer) will get OP started

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd267312.aspx) which provides [a constructor that lets you specify an upper bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd267301.aspx) for the queue.

Alternatively, if you just want to discard the oldest items when it is full, you may need a [Circular Buffer](http://circularbuffer.codeplex.com/) (also [see here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)).

Here's a sample implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

namespace Demo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A circular buffer with a maximum capacity set at construction time.
    /// You can repeatedly add elements to this buffer; once it has reached its capacity
    /// the oldest elements in it will be overwritten with the newly added ones.
    /// This is how it differs from a queue: Oldest elements will be overwritten when the buffer is full.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the elements stored in the buffer.</typeparam>

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1710:IdentifiersShouldHaveCorrectSuffix", Justification = "Calling this CircularBufferCollection would be stupid.")]

    public class CircularBuffer<T>: IEnumerable<T>
    {
        /// <summary>Constructor.</summary>
        /// <param name="capacity">The maximum capacity of the buffer.</param>

        public CircularBuffer(int capacity)
        {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(capacity > 0, "Capacity must be greater than zero.");

            // We will use a buffer with a size one greater than the capacity.
            // The reason for this is to simplify the logic - we can use "front == back" to indicate an empty buffer.

            _buffer = new T[capacity+1];
        }

        /// <summary>A delegate that is called when an element is added to the buffer.</summary>

        public ElementAddedAlert OnElementAdded
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

         /// <summary>A delegate that is called when an element is overwritten in the buffer.</summary>

        public ElementOverwrittenAlert OnElementOverwritten
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>A delegate that is called when a single element is removed from the buffer.</summary>

        public ElementRemovedAlert OnElementRemoved
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>A delegate that is called when the buffer is emptied.</summary>

        public Action OnBufferEmptied
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>The buffer capacity.</summary>

        public int Capacity
        {
            get
            {
                Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() > 0);
                return _buffer.Length - 1;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>The number of elements currently stored in the buffer.</summary>

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                Contract.Ensures(0 <= Contract.Result<int>() && Contract.Result<int>() <= this.Capacity);

                int result = _back - _front;

                if (result < 0)
                {
                    result += _buffer.Length;
                }

                return result;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Is the buffer empty?</summary>

        public bool IsEmpty
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Count == 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Is the buffer full? (i.e. has it reached its capacity?)</summary>

        public bool IsFull
        {
            get
            {
                return nextSlot(_back) == _front;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Empties the buffer.</summary>

        public void Empty()
        {
            Contract.Ensures(this.IsEmpty);

            _front = _back = 0;
            Array.Clear(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length); // Destroy any old references so they can be GCed.
            var onEmptied = this.OnBufferEmptied;    // Copy for thread-safeness.

            if (onEmptied != null)
            {
                onEmptied();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Add an element to the buffer, overwriting the oldest element if the buffer is full.</summary>
        /// <param name="newItem">The element to add.</param>

        public void Add(T newItem)
        {
            _buffer[_back] = newItem;
            _back = nextSlot(_back);

            if (_back == _front) // Buffer is full?
            {
                _front = nextSlot(_front); // Bump the front, overwriting the current front.
                var onValueOverwritten = this.OnElementOverwritten; // Copy for thread-safeness.

                if (onValueOverwritten != null)
                {
                    onValueOverwritten(newItem, _buffer[_back], this.Capacity);
                }

                _buffer[_back] = default(T); // Remove the old front value.
            }
            else // Buffer is not full.
            {
                var onValueAdded = this.OnElementAdded; // Copy for thread-safeness.

                if (onValueAdded != null)
                {
                    onValueAdded(newItem, this.Count);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Removes and returns the oldest element from the buffer.</summary>
        /// <returns>The element that was removed from the buffer.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown if the buffer is empty.</exception>

        public T RemoveOldestElement()
        {
            Contract.Requires<InvalidOperationException>(!this.IsEmpty, "Cannot remove an element from an empty buffer.");

            T result = _buffer[_front];
            _buffer[_front] = default(T); // Zap the front element.
            _front = nextSlot(_front);

            var onElementRemoved = this.OnElementRemoved; // Copy for thread-safeness.

            if (onElementRemoved != null)
            {
                onElementRemoved(result, this.Count);
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The typesafe enumerator. Elements are returned in oldest to newest order.
        /// This is not threadsafe, so if you are enumerating the buffer while another thread is changing it you will run
        /// into threading problems. Therefore you must use your own locking scheme to avoid the problem.
        /// </summary>

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            for (int i = _front; i != _back; i = nextSlot(i))
            {
                yield return _buffer[i];
            }
        }

        /// <summary>The non-typesafe enumerator.</summary>

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator(); // Implement in terms of the typesafe enumerator.
        }

        /// <summary>The delegate used for <see cref="OnElementAdded"/>.</summary>
        /// <param name="addedElement">The element that was added.</param>
        /// <param name="newCount">The new count after the element was added.</param>

        public delegate void ElementAddedAlert(T addedElement, int newCount);

        /// <summary>The delegate used for <see cref="OnElementOverwritten"/>.</summary>
        /// <param name="addedElement">The element that was added.</param>
        /// <param name="overwrittenElement">The element that was overwritten.</param>
        /// <param name="newCount">
        /// The new count after the element was added.
        /// By definition this will be equal to <see cref="Capacity"/>.
        /// </param>

        public delegate void ElementOverwrittenAlert(T addedElement, T overwrittenElement, int newCount);

        /// <summary>The delegate used for <see cref="OnElementRemoved"/>.</summary>
        /// <param name="removedElement">The removed element.</param>
        /// <param name="newCount">The new count after the element was removed.</param>

        public delegate void ElementRemovedAlert(T removedElement, int newCount);

        /// <summary>Calculates the index of the slot following the specified one, wrapping if necessary.</summary>

        private int nextSlot(int slot)
        {
            return (slot + 1) % _buffer.Length;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The index of the element at the front of the buffer. 
        /// If this equals _back, the buffer is empty.
        /// </summary>

        private int _front;

        /// <summary>
        /// The index of the first element BEYOND the last used element of the buffer. 
        /// Therefore this indicates where the next added element will go.
        /// </summary>

        private int _back;

        /// <summary>The underlying buffer. This has a length one greater than the actual capacity.</summary>

        private readonly T[] _buffer;
    }
}
```